# What's the best way to reload python query module during development?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm working on my first query module for Memgraph. I'm trying to find the best approach.

I have a query module that depends on a local submodule (`firstone`):

```
import firstone
import mgp
import importlib

@mgp.read_proc
def procedure(context...):
    importlib.reload(firstone)
    firstone.call()
```

If I get it correctly, if `firstone` module changes, the procedure is still using the previous code. How can I reload the Python query module during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the use `mg.load` to load or reload the given module. The correct syntax is `CALL mg.load("py_example");`. After loading the module, all dependent Python's submodules that are imported will also be reloaded. The official documentation can be found on [Memgraph site](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/query-modules/module-file-utilities).